# Using scoped beans to handle AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: java, spring

I followed [this tutorial](http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) from 2007 to learn how to set up multiple, selectable `DataSource` instances with *Spring*:

My question is that since the article is quite old is there a better way to do this now instead of using `ThreadLocal`?

I attempted to use a session-scoped bean to accomplish the same thing, but I kept getting the infamous `No thread-bound request found` error.

Comment: have you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: Just used the ThreadLocal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely use a scoped proxy to achieve the same result, but whether it is better to do so would depend to a large extent on how you deploy your application.

If it is a web app, then you can get a scoped proxy in a number of ways, see for instance:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html

If it is a standalone app then you *could* implement your own custom scope:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-custom

But if you're just binding to a threadlocal then there's not much point.

Comment: Definitely the kind of thing that I was looking to do, but adding the `RequestContextListener` as a `@Bean` in my Spring boot application doesn't do the trick... even though that's how it's supposed to work. It fails on startup with the `No thread-bound request found` error.

Comment: Are you deploying as a web app?

Comment: I am, but using the `main` method approach provided by Spring Boot. I'm not familiar with the exact mechanics of how it handles deploying within the embedded Tomcat, etc.